# JAVA Spring : Service returning a null

Tags: java, spring

For some reason, my service is returning a null. The autowires are correct, the service annotation is there, the getters and setters .. But this returns a null :

```
public PlatformService getPlatformService() {
    return platformService;
}

public void setPlatformService(PlatformService platformService) {
    this.platformService = platformService;
}
```

on Debug, it returns platformService = null

Here is my PlatformService :

```
package empsuite.service;
    import java.util.List;
import empsuite.model.Platform;



public interface PlatformService {
    public void addPlatform(Platform platform);
    public void updatePlatform(Platform platform);
    public Platform getPlatformById(int id);
    public List<Platform> getPlatform();

}
```

PlatformServiceImpl :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PlatformServiceImpl implements PlatformService {
    @Autowired
    PlatformDAO platformDAO;

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void addPlatform(Platform platform) {
        getPlatformDAO().addPlatform(platform);
    }
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void updatePlatform(Platform platform) {
        getPlatformDAO().updatePlatform(platform);
    }


    private PlatformDAO getPlatformDAO() {
        return platformDAO; }

    public void setPlatformDAO(PlatformDAO platformDAO) {
        this.platformDAO = platformDAO;
    }

    public Platform getPlatformById(int id) {
        return getPlatformDAO().getPlatformById(id);
    }

    public List<Platform> getPlatform() {
        return getPlatformDAO().getPlatform();
    }
}
```

The DAOImpl function (with sessionfactory autowired) as it is the builder of the HQL :

```
public List<Platform> getPlatform() {
    List list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Platform").list();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Wild guess you are doing `new PlatformServiceImpl` in the code containing the getter and setter for it.

Comment: how are you injecting the PlatformService , to the class that is using it ?

Comment: M. Deinum certainly not !

Comment: Antjavadev : @ManagedProperty(value="#{PlatformService}")
    PlatformService platformService;
    List<Platform> platformList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ManagedProperty is the cause of the problem, so I overriden it and it works with this constructor :

```
public PlatformManagedBean() {
    super();
    if(platformService == null){
        WebApplicationContext ctx =  FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
        platformService = ctx.getBean(PlatformService.class);
    }

}
```